# Considering SSD upgrade for 13" Mid-2012 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssd

My Macbook's HDD is starting to show signs of age and I'm considering replacing it with a Samsung 850 EVO 500GB SSD. I know and am comfortable with the actual hardware replacement, but I heard that the newest Mac; OS El Capitan, has some "feature" to prevent using third party SSDs. Something to do with TRIM if I remember right. I would like to know if that is an actual problem or if I can go ahead and make the purchase.

Thank you very much!

P.S. I'd like to point out that this will be a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

OS X 10.11, El Capitan, does not include specific code to prevent the use of a third party Solid State Disk (SSD).

I have replaced my MacBook Pro's Hard Disk Drive (HDD) with a Samsung SSD; the MacBook is running OS X 10.11.

With regard to `TRIM` support on non-Apple installed drives, see [Should I enable TRIM with a third party (non-Apple) SSD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56457/should-i-enable-trim-with-a-third-party-non-apple-ssd)

Answer (score 0):

Apple's SSDs are officially supported in OS X and TRIM feature is enabled by default for them. But for third party SSDs there is native builtin command to enable TRIM support. I followed [this](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+Dual+Hard+Drive/8529) tutorial to add and SSD to my MacBook Pro with HD caddy. Although now I realized that I don't use previous HDD day to day.

There is no problem for me since I started to use the new third party Samsung 850 EVO SSD. I used [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/222077/how-to-enable-trim-for-third-party-ssds-on-mac-os-x/) tutorial to enable TRIM support:

```
sudo trimforce enable
```

Comment: In my experience I would recommend replacing the stock HDD in an Apple laptop with something faster / reliable such as the WD 1TB Black 64MB. Then replace the optical drive with an SSD. Run the OS and apps off the SSD, everything else from the HDD (including User Folders). This will keep the SSD relatively clean and aid longevity ensuring that you have a fast OS, boot and app launch. Side note, max the RAM as laptops by default are dumbed down for heat and battery life unless you have a workstation like the MacBookPro 17" which runs different setups on battery / power.